# Data for Two Months ago

Tags: sql-server

I have a basic transactions table and the below query gets me a count of all transactions for last full month:

```
Select count(status)
FROM TX 
WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

What I want is to compare that value with the previous full month and find a % increase or decrease.

For example, we are in july, above query will give me a count of transactions for June (ie 100). I need count of the whole of May (2 months ago) and find % difference. So if May was 50, June is 100 so query should return 100%

Any ideas?

Comment: Providing sample data would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Window functions:

```
with cte as(
select year(Date_reported) as [Year], month(Date_reported) as [Month], count(Status) as [StatusCount]
FROM TX
group by year(Date_reported), month(Date_reported)
)
Select [Year], [Month], [StatusCount]
    , 100.0*([StatusCount] - lag([StatusCount]) OVER (ORDER BY [Year], [Month]))/lag([StatusCount]) OVER (ORDER BY [Year], [Month]) as [PercentageDiff]
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a go to below approach, should work fine however do not think it is the best solution:

```
declare @lastMonth int = 
  (Select count(status)
  FROM TX 
  WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
    AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0))

declare @beforeLastMonth int = 
  (Select count(status)
  FROM TX 
  WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-2,0)
    AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0))


declare @result int = (@lastMonth - @beforeLastMonth) * 100 / @beforeLastMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need just for 2 months then you can try following query. Otherwise you can add series (1,2,3,4,5...) and then use it instead of the fixed integers:

```
CREATE TABLE tx
(
    status        CHAR(1)
  , date_reported DATE
);

INSERT INTO tx
VALUES ('A', '20180709')
     , ('B', '20180708')
     , ('A', '20180701')
     , ('B', '20180609')
     , ('A', '20180608')
     , ('A', '20180509')
     , ('B', '20180501');

  SELECT       SUM(months.is_last_month)
           , SUM(months.is_last2_month)
           , (SUM(months.is_last_month) - SUM(months.is_last2_month)) * 100 / SUM(months.is_last2_month)
  FROM       tx                                AS t
 OUTER APPLY (   SELECT CASE WHEN Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
                             AND  Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) THEN 1
                        END AS is_last_month
                      , CASE WHEN Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0)
                              AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) THEN 1
                        END AS is_last2_month) AS months
 WHERE       t.date_reported >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0)
   AND       t.date_reported       < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with CurMon as (
  Select count(status) CurStat
  FROM TX 
  WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
  AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
)
,
 PreMon as (
  Select count(status) PreStat
  FROM TX 
  WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-2,0)
  AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
)

select  case when PreStat>0 then 100*(CurStat-  PreStat)/PreStat else 0 end as pct
from CurMon  join PreMon on 1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to do it in a pl/sql function, because is easier:

```
DECLARE
FUNCTION  this() RETURN float
IS
    month1 number;
    month2 number;
    increment float;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(status)
INTO month1
FROM TX 
WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
    AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)

SELECT COUNT(status)
INTO month2
FROM TX 
WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-2,0)
    AND Date_Reported < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)

increment = month1 - month2;

RETURN (increment / month1) * 100;
END
```

Without the tables is hard to try a solution in only one Query

Comment: @Taz You are welcome, but I miss the types a lot sorry for that, is just a quick mockup